# IBM MFP v8: NullPointerException while calling Java Adapter from Java Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

My MFP Version is **8.0.0-2017012016**.

When I am trying to call a Java Adapter from other Java Adapter, it is always throwing NullPointerException at the line:

```
HttpResponse response = adapterAPI.executeAdapterRequest(req);
```

What I have done is create the adapter named Producer, which contains method named **sayHello** which I am calling from Consumer Adapter.

Consumer Adapter contains method named **getHello**, which is consuming above mentioned **sayHello** method.

I have tested `sayHello` method alone and it is working fine.

I have tested the `getHello` method using `WLResourceRequest` and also with `Swagger`, but it is always throwing error.

Here is the link to download both the [adapters](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6nkcfbiou25nz1/Producer_Consumer_Adapters.zip?dl=0). Both adapters are inside zip file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Not real keen on downloading a zip file, you did this? https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/advanced-adapter-usage-mashup/#java-adapter-api